# How to define two C++ constructors with two different type having same base type

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two simple type defined as int:

```
typedef int type_a;
typedef int type_b;
```

I would like to create a constructor for each type in a class. I tried with explicit keyword, but it doesn't work i got a compilation message "cannot be overloaded".

```
class Test {
public:
  explicit Test(type_a a){

  }
  explicit Test(type_b b){

  }
};
```

Changing one type to unsigned (typedef unsigned int type_b;) fix the problem but i really want to keep both type defined identically.

Is C++ can handle this case?

Comment: `typedef`s are *aliases* for types. So `type_a` and `type_b` are the same type: `int`. So you can't do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: You can wrap the `int`s up in two separate classes. Perhaps if `type_a` and `type_b` do really represent different types, then you might be able to define different interfaces for these types.

Comment: You should tell us *why* you want to have `type_a` and `type_b` both be `int`. Then we can understand the problem you're trying to solve (instead of your solution) and suggest a sane approach to the *actual* underlying problem.

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark about your requirements: You may want to take a look at scoped enums.

Comment: Well i simplified the problem for the question, but my type are defined as uint32_t. One is an audio_id and the other a video_id. The class represent a DataType defined with these attribute "Type type; union { audio_id aid; video_id vid;};".  I need uint32_t because i'm writing and reading it to a file.

Answer (score 8):

> Can C++ handle this case?

Short answer: no. `typedef`s are *aliases* for types. So `type_a` and `type_b` are the same type: `int`. Which means you are trying to do this:

```
class Test {
public:
  explicit Test(int a) {}
  explicit Test(int b) {}
};
```

Since it isn't clear *why* you want this, it is hard to suggest possible solutions. But if you were to implement a distinct integer type, the you could have a separate constructor for it.

Also note that `explicit` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As i told above, i simplified the problem for the question, but my type are defined as uint32_t. One is an audio_id and the other a video_id. The class represent a DataType defined with these attribute "Type type; union { audio_id aid; video_id vid;};". I need uint32_t because i'm writing and reading it to a file.

Comment: @SaiyanRiku But why do you need a union to hold two entities of the same type? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Because for now i have only two types, but i can possibly add more type later, maybe with another type definition (uint16_t), and audio related function deal with an audio_id, and video function with a video_id.

Comment: @SaiyanRiku But you don't have two types. You only have one. That is the point.

Comment: I understand what you means, but constructor are different, one set "type = Video; this->video_id = video_id;" and the others "type = Audio; this->audio_id = audio_id;", i can accept changing the union to a unique uint32_t variable, but my problem are the calling constructor. I want to cast defined video_id (#define VIDEO_H264 MAKE_FOURCC('H','2','6','4')) to use DataType(VIDEO_H264).

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to wrap the parameters with a template type that includes a 'domain':

```
template <typename Type, typename Domain>
class TypeWrapper {
public:
   TypeWrapper(Type);
   operator Type ();
};

typedef int type_a;
typedef int type_b;

typedef TypeWrapper<type_a, class type_a_domain> type_a_wrapper;
typedef TypeWrapper<type_b, class type_b_domain> type_b_wrapper;

class Test {
public:
  explicit Test(type_a_wrapper a);
  explicit Test(type_b_wrapper b);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried it but it doesn't fully solve my problem because i have to add cast for the type wrapper => Test a((type_a)val); doesn't work.

Comment: @SaiyanRiku: juanchopanza's answer is correct, you cannot distinguish two typedefs to the same underlying type in C++.  The idea is to try to use 'type_a_wrapper' in your code rather than 'type_a'?  For example, an API that returns 'type_a' would be immediately converted to a type_a_wrapper.  For example;  `type_a_wrapper var_ ( call_returning_type_a() );  Test t(var_);`